# need to define up and bottom rows. vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon!
I need help for setting first and last rows.
Here is an example I need to modify:

```
Set thisrng = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp))
For Each cell In thisrng
```

This code takes the selected cell as upper and goes down to the last row in active column.
I need to define my first cell as A2 and go down to the last row - 2

Thank you very much!
Kind Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work although you should change "Sheet1" for the name of the worksheet:

```
Set thisrng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & (Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row)-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work:

```
Dim thisrng As Range
Dim TwoRowsFromTheBottom As Long

TwoRowsFromTheBottom = Columns("A").Rows.Count - 2

Set thisrng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(TwoRowsFromTheBottom, "A"))
```

You can also just include the `Columns("A").Rows.Count - 2` into the `Set thisrng .....`